# What is the value of the variable after a for...of loop completes?

Tags: javascript

I have an application for using the final value of an array as the default.  I tried:

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
for (var zz of x) {};
console.log(zz);   // 3
```

This is exactly what I wanted, but I was wondering if this is defined behavior of a for...of loop or just a fortuitous result of the implementation.  I couldn't find the answer, so was hoping someone here could answer that (preferably with a reference).

Clarification:  The answers and comments thus far are a bit off point.  The example above shows that the final value is, in fact the last value of the array.  My question is that just an unspecified result of the implementation of the formal definition of the for..of loop, or part of the formal definition.

Comment: Even though Javascript does *NOT* have [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), I would suggest *NOT* defining zz *INSIDE* the loop if you intended to use its value outside of the loop.  Defining zz *outside* of the loop shows "intent" to use it outside of the loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zz` is declared using `var`, so it is ["hoisted"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). This means that the scope extends outside of the `for` loop.

Since `3` was assigned to `zz` at the end, `zz` will be `3` when the loop finishes.

Comment: Actually, my question was about the final value of zz when the loop is complete.  e.g. is it defined as the final value of the loop?

Comment: Well, I had reached that conclusion myself, but failed to find that as defined loop behavior.  Was hoping to see a formal definition of the loop that said that.

Comment: Wordragon - when you hoist the variable you make it part of the larger scope. Then the last time through your loop, it is assigned a value of 3. So that is what you see when you call console.log

Comment: @wordragon I don't think that you'll find this behaviour documented somewhere. It will be like explaining that `a = 5;` means that `a` is set to `5`. The `for...of` loop just loops the entire array assigning the current value from the array to the variable `zz`, so by the end of the loop, `zz` will be the last item of the array. It's just that simple!

Comment: Well, I appreciate your point, but there is a difference between things that happen to work because the implementation of the formal definition happen to leave something unspecified in a particular state, and things that are actually part of the formal language definition.  I prefer to avoid relying on the former, but like utilizing the latter.

Comment: @wordragon everything that is happening here is formally defined. The scoping of `var zz` is defined, the behavior of a for loop is defined. What part do you think is missing a formal definition?

Comment: Well, specifically, hoping to find something which says after the loop completes, the variable retains the final value in the loop.  I've looked through a number of the definitions, and none actually say that.  Happy to see one that does.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was looking for was in the [ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).  The use case is in 13.7.5.11:

```
IterationStatement : for ( var ForBinding of AssignmentExpression ) Statement
    1. Let keyResult be the result of performing ? ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(« »,  AssignmentExpression, iterate).
    2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(ForBinding, Statement, keyResult, iterate, varBinding, labelSet).
```

When you slog through 13.7.5.12-13, with those parameters, it appears boil down to everyone's observation (though maybe not *quite* as obvious as a = 5:-).  So check to jh314 for saying that first.